# ExtTextOutW not showing some unicode characters

Tags: winapi, unicode, c++17

I am currently using Visual Studio 2022 (C++) to develop a simple desktop application.

I have included `#define UNICODE` in my code.

However, I have tried `ExtTextOutW()`, `TextOutW()` and `DrawText()` but neither of them showed what I had expected. For example, I used the following code with `ExtTextOutW()`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    // ... omitted
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        RECT rec;
        SetRect(&rec, 10, 10, 100, 100);
        ExtTextOutW(hdc, 0, 0, NULL, &rec, L"中文字", 3, nullptr);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The outcome (in the window) was [image], instead of `中文字`. Similarly, if I use `L"\u210E"` or `L"\U0001D465"` (or other unicode characters in the block [*Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols*](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1D400)) the outcome is always [image] (two characters give two `|`, so on and on). From my observation, ascii characters like `L"abc"` worked, though.

May I ask what may possibly solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are passing `ETO_GLYPH_INDEX`, but your string consists of characters, not glyph indices.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you! I changed to `NULL`. But the problem still persists.

Comment: You're not selecting a font so the DC will have the default system font, which may not be able to render those characters.

Comment: @JonathanPotter For the title bar it works very well (the default font can show such characters). Could you please show me how to select a font for showing text inside the window?

Comment: This is explained under [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts). The title bar isn't rendered using the GDI. Its default font and the font a DC uses as the default font may not be the same thing.

Comment: @IInspectable Could you please write an answer for this question on how to specify a font to use inside the window?

Comment: @TonyMa look at the `CreateFont/Indirect()` and `SelectObject()` functions.